# Best practice for multi-page application using Rails and Angular?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router

There are tons of tutorials out there for creating single page applications using Rails and Angular.  They usually pass all the routing to Angular and leave Rails for the activerecord stuff.  I find this frustrating because there are times when I just want a plain HTML page with minimal client side bells and whistles.

What is the best practice for a multi-page application, where I can use both Rails routes and Angular UI-router?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Angular router so all of your routes are in one place.  The best part about angular is you can add as much or as little as you want.  So you can have static pages handled by the angular router.